# How to remove/handle irrelevant or bad sort parameters from http url using Pageable interface in spring boot?

Tags: spring-data, pageable

How to remove/handle irrelevant or bad sort parameters from http url using Pageable interface in spring boot?

For e.g. I have a query like
http://localhost:8080/all?sort=firstName,asc&sort=nosuchfield,asc

How can I handle or remove the irrelevant field "nosuchfield"?

Also, how can I limit sort parameters in URL?

Answer (score 0):

If the sorting field doesn't present in the database then below exception will be thrown by Spring JPA.

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property nosuchfield found for type <TYPE>!

    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:382)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358)
```

However, the exception can be handled using various types. Ultimately, you can just log it or transform it into any custom exception. As per my requirement, I have transformed it into a custom exception.

1. Using AOP

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class UnKnownColumnSortingExceptionHandler {
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.repositorypackage.*.*(..))", throwing = "exception")
    public void executeWhenExceptionThrowninRepository(JoinPoint jp, Throwable ex) {
        if (ex instanceof PropertyReferenceException) {
            throw new CustomException("Invalid Database operation");
        }
    }
}
```

2. Using **`@ControllerAdvice`**(Exception handling in Application wise)

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    public GlobalExceptionHandler() {}
    @ExceptionHandler({PropertyReferenceException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Void> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest req) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

3. Exception handling in Controller wise

Add the below piece of code to your controller

```
    @ExceptionHandler({PropertyReferenceException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Void> handleAllExceptions(Exception ex, WebRequest req) 
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

Comment: How can we handle this error in restcontroller api?

Comment: modified the answer as per your requirement

Comment: Thank you will try the last one and will get back to you!

Comment: Can we limit the sort parameters in controller or service level?

Comment: `Iterator<Sort.Order> iterator = pageable.getSort().iterator();` , Pagable#getSort will provide you the iterator the requested fields and you can set the size limit check or any other business condition in your Service class

Comment: Spring is not throwing any exception for invalid sort params. I am using MongoRepository. How to handle field exceptions in mongodb? Also I need to limit or handle the sort parameters in a config file not in controller...how can i globalise that?

Comment: Surely it will throw an exception for an unknown column name,  and I don't find any out-of-the-box sorting properties related to limit the sorting `https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#data-properties`

Comment: I am trying to implement using this:

Comment: The controller call bypasses the non existing sorting fields meaning instead of throwing exception its ignores the invalid sort fields and returns unsorted result. I believe Pageable implementation doesn’t help in throwing exception. How can I replace default SortArgumentResolver meaning how can I use resolvearguement method of SortArguementHandlerResolver class and include it inPageableArguementHandlerResolver class to limit and handle the invalid sort fields?Please provide some code example .

Comment: I have implemented this. Its working. But I am not sure how to propagate the exception from the Customized SortArguementHandlerResolver class to Controller method.

Comment: Have implemted a workng soln. But not sure how to propagate the exception from the CustomizedSortArguementHandlerResolver class to handler method in Controller class.                                                                                                        
 @Override
 public Sort resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter,ModelAndViewContainer modelViewContainer, NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest,WebDataBinderFactory webDataBinderFactory)  {
....//some logic....
if (orders.size() >= 2) {
 throw new InvalidSortException(); }
 catch (Exception e) {
e.msg}return sort;  }

Comment: I hope you would have tried the `@ExceptionHandler({InvalidSortException.class})`, doesn't help it for your case?